# How to call functions in a console in a javascript prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have used the following code from the below's answer to my initial question:

```js
const myForm = {
  text : "Hello",
  span1: '<span>',
  span2: '</span>',
  p1: '<p>',
  p2: '</p>',
  span: function() {
this.text = this.span1 + this.text + this.span2;
return this;
  },
  p: function() {
this.text = this.p1 + this.text + this.p2;
return this;
  }
};

console.log(myForm.p().span().text)
```

How to modify the code to receive `<p><span>Hello</span></p>` in console.log(myForm.p().span()), because it adds the tags in the wrong order, first p() and than span() and I need first span() around text and than p() ?

Comment: Do you really need `myForm.p().span()` or could it be `myForm.p(myForm.span())`?

Comment: Please learn about the builder pattern. This article should help you: https://dzone.com/articles/builder-pattern-in-javascript

Comment: @yunzen - yes, that is my assignment I need to figure out.

Comment: @derry Now. Would `span().p()` work or must it be `p().span()`?

Comment: @derry Then look at Jeremy's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, since you want methods to be chainable, each method must `return this`, not a string. It means that `console.log(myForm.p().span())` will return the full object. You could do something like the following :

```js
const myForm = {
  text : "Hello",
  span1: '<span>',
  span2: '</span>',
  p1: '<p>',
  p2: '</p>',
  span: function() {
    this.text = this.span1 + this.text + this.span2;
    return this;
  },
  p: function() {
    this.text = this.p1 + this.text + this.p2;
    return this;
  }
};

console.log(myForm.span().p().text)
```

You could even go further, and for instance make one single parametric method :

```js
const myForm = {
  text : "Hello",
  wrap : function(elems) {
    for(let elem of elems.split(",")){
      this.text = `<${elem}>${this.text}</${elem}>`
    }
    return this;
  }
};

console.log(myForm.wrap("span,p,div,header").text);
```

Comment: Looks good, however this changes the original text field of the object as a consequence.

Comment: @Jeremy Thille, very nice, very close.

Comment: @Jeremy Thille, of course, that was another part of the assignment, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `p` function to take a variable to surround, and use `myForm.span()` as the input.

```js
var myForm = {
  span1: '<span>',
  span2: '</span>',
  p1: '<p>',
  p2: '</p>',
  span: function() {
    return this.span1 + "Hello" + this.span2
  },
  p: function(target) {
    return this.p1 + target + this.p2
  },
};

console.log(myForm.p(myForm.span()))
```

Comment: I don't know how strict the asker wants function chaining over your solution.

Comment: this is not what OP wants.

Comment: Thank you. That works, but is there a way to reach the same effect like this: console.log(myForm.p().span()) ?

Comment: @derry you would have to return an object with a `.p()` function to do that.

Comment: @ bluevulture, thanks, already tried similar solutions, they returned me errors.

Answer (score -1):

use `createElement` , `createTextNode` and `appendChild`

```
function addElement () {
  // create a new span and p element
  const newP = document.createElement("p");
  const newSpan = document.createElement("span");

  // and give it some content
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
  newSpan.appendChild(textnode)
  // add the text node to the newly created span
  newP.appendChild(newSpan);

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  const currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newP, currentDiv);
}

addElement()
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question...?

Comment: @MA Rahman, thank you for a solution. I have made already something similiar, but this solution was not accepted.